# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Assembly and C code

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I'm new to C and Assembly and I'm having difficulty figuring out why I'm getting a segmentation fault in my code. In this current assignment, I have to create 4 assembly programs that link into my main c program. I'm only working on the first function which is the sumOfPowers function but I'm getting my segmentation fault there. Here is my main function:

```
#include "something.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Customer {
  int id;
  int age;
  int payments[5];
} CUSTOMER;

typedef struct Employee {
  char name[8];
  int salary;
} EMPLOYEE;

int sumOfPowers(int n);                                 //this function should find the following sum: 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + ... + n^2
// int compareAges(CUSTOMER* a, CUSTOMER* b);              //this function should test if  a->age == b->age. it returns 1 if they are equal; 0 otherwise.
// int findPaymentsSum(CUSTOMER* c, int num_of_pamyments); //this function should find the sum of all payments made by a given customer
// int findSalariesSum(EMPLOYEE e[], int size);            //this function should find the sum of salaries in a given array of employees

int main() {

  // TestCase-1
  printf("The sum is: %d\n", sumOfPowers(3));

  // TestCase-2
  /*
  CUSTOMER* a1=malloc(sizeof(CUSTOMER));
  CUSTOMER* a2=malloc(sizeof(CUSTOMER));
  CUSTOMER* a3=malloc(sizeof(CUSTOMER));
  a1->age=25;
  a2->age=30;
  a3->age=25;
  printf("The result of the comparison is: %d\n",compareAges(a1,a2));
  printf("The result of the comparison is: %d\n",compareAges(a1,a3));
  */

  // TestCase-3
  /*
  CUSTOMER* cstmr=malloc(sizeof(CUSTOMER));
  cstmr->id=101;
  cstmr->age=30;
  cstmr->payments[0]=1500;
  cstmr->payments[1]=1500;
  cstmr->payments[2]=2000;
  cstmr->payments[3]=500;
  cstmr->payments[4]=300;
  printf("The sum of all payments is: %d\n",findPaymentsSum(cstmr, 5));
  */

  // TestCase-4

  // EMPLOYEE e1={"jame",2000}, e2={"sara",3000}, e3={"alic",2500},
  // e4={"mark",3200}; EMPLOYEE employees[4]={e1,e2,e3,e4}; printf("The sum of
  // salaries is: %d\n",findSalariesSum(employees,4));
}
```

Here is my sumOfPowers.s function:

```
 .globl sumOfPowers

sumOfPowers:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    # Input: n in %rdi
    # Output: Result in %rax

    # Initialize x to 0
    mov %rax, 0

    # Initialize i to 1
    mov %rcx, 1

loop_start:
    # Calculate i^2
    mov %rdx, %rcx     # Move the value of i from %rcx to %rdx
    imul %rdx, %rdx    # Calculate i^2 and store it in %rdx 

    # Add i^2 to x
    add %rax, %rdx

    # Increment i
    inc %rcx

    # Check if we've reached the end of the loop
    cmp %rcx, %rdi     # Compare the current value of i (in %rcx) with n (in %rdi)
    jle loop_start

    pop %rbp

    # The result is now in %rax, you can return it
    ret
```

I tried using different registers, but nothing has really worked. It is important to note that I'm using Repl.it so i'm using whatever computer architecture is being used there.

Comment: at&t syntax uses source, destination order. Also you need to use a `$` prefix on immediates.

Comment: It looks like you are using Intel syntax (no operand size suffixes), in which case `mov %rsp, %rbp` is moving in the wrong direction

Comment: @RaymondChen: AT&T syntax doesn't need operand-size suffixes when a register operand implies the size. You only need `movl` instead of `mov` in cases like `movl $1, (%rdi)` or `negb (%rsi)` where there are no register operands.  It's a style choice; I prefer leaving the size implicit, just like in Intel syntax where I omit the `dword ptr` when possible.  But yes, the OP does seem to have written everything except the RBP frame-pointer setup as if it was Intel syntax (based on operand-order and lack of `$` decoration on immediates), but forgot to use `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

Comment: (Or I guess `.intel_syntax prefix` if they want a confusing mutant hybrid syntax which still uses `%` decorations on register names but not `$` on immediates, and dst,src order, so they only have to change the `mov %rsp, %rbp`.  Clang doesn't support that for good reason, only `.att_syntax prefix` or `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  GAS actually accepts `%` on reg names in `noprefix` modes, clang doesn't)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the clarification. Given that the problem is at runtime, I assumed that this code assembled successfully, and "intel syntax prefix" (or "index syntax noprefix" in gas) are the only ones that would accept this code. (att syntax would reject the missing `$` and the attempt to move to an immediate.)

Comment: It assembles in stock at&t mode. The missing `$` causes a memory reference to be generated which will then fault matching the observed behavior.

Comment: @RaymondChen: This is valid AT&T syntax for non-useful instructions that don't match the comments, like `mov %rcx, 1` store to absolute address `1`, with a `[disp32]` addressing mode.  You're correct that `mov %rcx, $1` wouldn't assemble because an immediate can't be a destination, but without the `$` it isn't an immediate.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your patience. So this code happens to be unlucky that it is a polyglot that produces very different code depending on the invisible assembler switches. Like a poem that can be interpreted as both English and French but with radically different meanings.